# OpenBaseKey open and change a read-only registry key

Tags: vb.net, permissions, registry

I have a registry key that my users need access to in my VB.NET application. I have noticed that some users systems only have read only access to the registry key. I know how to correct this in `regedit`. However since this an integral part of my program I needed a way to do it pragmatically.

On the key the Administrators account is set to Read-Only.

I can change the rights if I can OpenSubKey the key.

```
Private Sub Main()
    Dim ProductKey As String
    ProductKey = "Software\My Application"

    Dim ApplicationsKey As String
    ApplicationsKey = ProductKey & "\Applications"

    Dim AppKey As String
    AppKey = ApplicationsKey & "\MyApp"

    Dim LM As RegistryKey
    LM = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)

    Dim CRKey As RegistryKey
    CKey = LM.OpenSubKey(AppKey, True)
End Sub
```

If the `opensubkey` is set writable true and the rights are write I can open and change the the key rights. If the rights are read-only I have to set `opensubkey` writable false to open the key. If the writable is set to false unable to change the rights.

```
Dim MyPath As String = "This is where registery key is"
Dim LM As RegistryKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)
Dim MyKey As RegistryKey = LM.OpenSubKey(MyPath, False)
Dim Trip = MyKey.GetAccessControl.AreAccessRulesProtected
If MyKey IsNot Nothing Then
    If Trip = False Then
        MsgBox(MyKey.Name)
    Else
        MsgBox(MyKey.Name & " is read-only")

        'This is where the hicup is. You cannot OpenSubKey/Write=True a key you do not have rights to.
        'You cannot edit the rights if OpenSubKey/Write=False.
        'I have to manually change the users rights in regedit.

    End If
Else
    MsgBox(MyPath & " Not Found.")
End If
```

The routine is running administator.

Comment: As far as I understand, under `RegistryHive.CurrentUser` it should work. Otherwise make your user start your app with `run as administrator`

Comment: Ok, must it be in the registry? It might be easier to use an XML file or [Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings)

Comment: The `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` hive is the installer's business (the application path and general settings, for example). Your app should deal with `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` hive. For user-defined settings. But, as djv said, the `Application.Settings` (or some custom format) may be a better choice.

Comment: It does work if the registry key is not read-only. If the key is read-only and you OpenSubKey(AppKey, True) it errors out.                                                                    if OpenSubKey(AppKey, False) it does not error out until you try to SetAccessControl.